# Use RegEx to match character unless "immediately" followed by another specific character

Tags: regex, linux

I am trying to find all matches which have a `[` except if followed immediately by a `'` or `"`.

For example, it would match a line with `bla bla bla [bla bla bla` but not `bla bla bla ['bla bla bla` or `bla bla bla ["bla bla bla`.

So, I tried the following

```
\[.+]/[[^'"][.+]
```

My (wrong) thinking is...

1. Use `\` to start.
2. Use `[.+]` to capture zero or more characters.
3. Use `/[` to first escape and then search for a right facing bracket.
4. Use `[^'"]` to not look for either a `'` or `"`.
5. Use `[.+]` to get the rest.

I really don't want to have to ask this question again for another situation, and would appreciate an explanation, and just not a regex which will work.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide an example of your data? And your escaping on the right square bracket should be `\[` not `/[`

Comment: Check my answer, perl code gives correct output for given examples

Answer (score 0):

My take would be

```
\[[^'"]+
```

`\[` escape the [
`[^'"]+` one or more times

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative look ahead in regex

YOu can use the regular expression

```
^.*\[(?!['"])
```

Tested in perl

```
if($str=~/^.*\[(?!['"])/){

        print "match";

}
```

Comment: Does it take the "sorry later requirement" immediately before part?

Comment: Don't understand what are you saying

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** after Alan's feedback here is a simplified version.

```
^.*?\[(?!['"]).*
```

**ORIGINAL**

This is a classic [password-validation-style problem](http://rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html). First I'll give you a solution and demo, then I'll explain, then I'll give you an even more compact solution that rolls both conditions into one.

This regex will work (see [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/qT4kH4), where only correct lines are matched):

```
^(?=.*?\[)(?!.*?\[['"]).*$
```

**How does it work?**

The recipe for this kind of problem is to express each condition in a lookaround, then, when we're satisfied, to match the whole string (which we do at the end with the `.*`

**First condition:** The line must contain a `[`

This is expressed by the lookahead `(?=.*?\[)` which asserts that at this point in the string (the very head because we anchored with `^`) we can match any number of any chars, followed by a `[`

**Second condition:** The line cannot contain a `['"`

This is expressed by the negative lookahead `(?!.*?\[['"])` which asserts that at this point in the string (the very head because we anchored with `^`) we cannot match any number of any chars followed by a `['` or `["`

**Rolling the Two Conditions into One**

This regex rolls both conditions into a single lookahead ([see demo](http://regex101.com/r/uV1nL1)):

```
^(?=.*?\[(?!['"])).*$
```

This time, there is a negative lookahead inside the single lookahead. The main lookahead says: at this point in the string (the very head because we anchored with `^`) we can match any number of any chars followed by a `[` which is not followed by a `'` or a `"`

Comment: I think you're making this more complicated than it needs to be.  All he said is there has to be a left square bracket that's not followed by an apostrophe or a quotation mark.  That's `\[(?!['"])`.  Come to think of it, your regex is exactly equivalent to mine, except yours doesn't allow newlines.

Comment: @AlanMoore You are right, the lookahead is not needed. It could be simplified to `^.*?\[(?!['"]).*` (remembering that he is trying to match whole lines)

Comment: @AlanMoore Added an EDIT at the top acknowledging your feedback. Sometimes I get caught in an idea and forget to step back and simplify at the end. :)