# How to Match Not Character After Repetition in Python Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to match any number that begins with one or two 1s, but not if immediately after that one or two ones there is a 3.

I want Regex to match the following:

```
1, 12, 11, 123, 111, 1113, 1123, 143, 1153, etc.
```

But I want Regex to **not** match:

```
0, 01, 21, 13, 113, 134, 11333, 135655..., etc.
```

As you can see, the number MUST start with 1. It can start with one 1 or two 1s, but it must start with at least one 1. Right after the 1(s), there cannot be a 3. After the one or two 1s, if there is no 3 immediately after the 1, there can be any number of digits (1632362382983598235 is valid).

I tried the following patterns (and many more, too), but none of them work:

```
re.fullmatch(r'^1{1,2}[^3].*','113')  # This matches '113' (it shouldn't), doesn't match '13' (as it shouldn't), but it also doesn't match '1' (it should)
re.fullmatch(r'^(11[^3]|1[^3]).*','113')  # Same as above
re.fullmatch(r'^(11(?!3))|(1(?!3)).*','113')  # This one actually allows '1', but it still allows '113'
```

(I know that '.*' matches any character, not just a digit.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For the first and the second strings, 3 is being matched in the `.*`.

Comment: @identicon I figured, but how, then, would I prevent that while still matching characters after?

Comment: Is a string allowed to start with 111? How about 1113?

Comment: @perigon Yes to both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured out a better solution (at least for my needs). I used a negative look-ahead:

```
^(?!1{1,2}3)1{1,2}.*
```

Explanation:

```
^              # Beginning of string
(?!1{1,2}3)    # Don't match if ^ is followed by one or two 1s and a 3
1{1,2}         # One to two 1s
.*             # Anything else is accepted
```

The best part about this is that it works the same as perigon's answer, but it is shorter, easier to read, and more easily adaptable.

**Edit:**

cdlane partially gave me a brilliant solution. I adapted it for `re.fullmatch` and it's more easily adaptable and shorter than my original by 1 byte:

```
^(?![^1]|1{1,2}3).*
```

Explanation:

```
^         # Beginning of string
(?!       # Do not match if
[^1]      # The string starts with anything other than 1
|1{1,2}3) # Or there is one or two 1s followed by a 3
.*        # Anything else is accepted
```

For anyone that's interested, you can also easily limit the number of 1s that can appear at the beginning by inserting:

```
|1{limit,}
```

Like this:

```
^(?![^1]|1{1,2}3|1{3,}).*
```

And if you want to change the number of 1s that *must* appear, instead of:

```
[^1]
```

Use:

```
(?!1{minimum,}
```

Putting it together:

```
^(?!(?!1{4,})|1{4,5}3|1{6,}).*
```

Comment: Nice pattern! (+1)  I'd change the comment on the 2nd segment to read "Don't match if ^ is followed by one or two 1s and a 3" to reinforce this is a negative lookahead from ^'s perspective (not to be confused with a negative lookbehind from the perspective of `1{1,2}` which might have worked if not for the variable pattern width.)

Comment: @cdlane Nice thinking.

Answer (score 1):

This does the job ([try it](https://pythex.org/?regex=(%5E1%7B1%2C2%7D%5B%5E13%5D.*)%7C(%5E1%7B3%7D.*)%7C%5E1%7B1%2C2%7D&test_string=1114%0A1113%0A1%0A12%0A11%0A123%0A1123%0A143%0A1153%0A0%0A01%0A21%0A13%0A113%0A134%0A11333%0A135655&ignorecase=0&multiline=1&dotall=0&verbose=0)):

```
(^1{1,2}[^13].*)|(^1{3}.*)|^1{1,2}
```

The left part covers the case of starting with 1 or 2 ones (and ensures neither a 1 nor a 3 follows that); the middle part covers the case of starting with 3 ones (then we don't care what follows); the right part covers '1' and '11'.

Comment: Thank you. It does seem to work, but I'm just curious as to why mine did not. Why does `^1{1,2}[^3].*` not catch both '13' and '113'? To me, it should be telling it: find one to two 1s, then not 3 (then anything after that).

Comment: @ClaytonGeist That's just not what `[^3]` does. It doesn't affect how the following `.*` will match anything anyways. If you're curious, you might be able to do this with lookaheads.

Comment: Oh, wait, I just found a problem. Yours doesn't match '1' or '11'.

Comment: Just add it to the OR. Try `(^1{1,2}[^13].*)|(^1{3}.*)|^1{1,2}`.

Comment: @identicon That works. It just seems a bit overly complicated, doesn't it? I mean, I know that regular expressions aren't simple, but all that just to prevent a 3 immediately after one to two ones? Maybe regex isn't the best solution for this particular problem, or maybe there's a simpler solution, but thanks, regardless.

Comment: @ClaytonGeist Seems nice enough for me. If you're interested, [there are other ways to tackle this problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750465/use-regex-to-match-character-unless-immediately-followed-by-another-specific-c)

I'll avoid editing the response for now, since @perigon's solution does seem to work on Pythex for `1` and `11`.

Comment: @identicon Yeah, I don't know what Pythex does, but in the Python (3.6.1) interpreter, `re.fullmatch(r'(^1{1,2}[^13].*)|(^1{3}.*)','1')` doesn't match the string.

Comment: @identicon seems to be a weird thing with Pythex's mutliline option... if you put in just 1 or 11, it doesn't match (nor should it). Will edit to include your fix.

Comment: @cdlane I'm interpreting OP's comment about . to mean that they don't care what happens for non-digits. Of course . could be replaced with \d or [0-9].

Comment: Yes, I now see that comment upon rereading the question.  Sorry.

Comment: Of all the current answers, this one seems to work the best for my situation, considering I was also looking for adaptability (I probably should have stated that in the question). We can easily adapt this to many similar situations, like: `(^1{1,5}[^1{1,4}3].*)|(^1{6}.*)|^1{1,5}`. That works for 1 from one up to five repetitions, and it can be easily changed to account for more or fewer. I will probably let this go for another day or two, just to make sure there aren't better solutions, but if none show, I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I emulate Wiktor Stribiżew's `re.match()` based approach, and eschew `re.fullmatch()`, then why doesn't the following obvious simple pattern meet the need:

```
import re
rx = r'([^1]|13|113)'
s = input()
m = re.match(rx, s)
if m:
    print("Invalid")
else:
    print("Valid")
```

I.e. if the number starts with a digit other then 1, or starts with 13 or starts with 113, reject it.  We're relying on the pattern to simply reject bad prefixes, not necessarily fully embrace good numbers.

Does this problem require "an atomic group/possessive quantifier workaround"?

Comment: Hah, this seems like the right way to think about it. The problem definitely doesn't _require_ any workarounds, it's certainly a regular language - as shown by the fact that it corresponds to the complement of the regular language your expression matches.

Comment: That would work. I think that, in the back of my mind, I thought of that. But what I was really looking for was a general purpose solution. What if, instead, we have `1{1,100}`? I suppose we *could* write a function that writes all the cases: `[^1]|13|113|1113|11113|111113...`, but that doesn't seem incredibly practical, not to mention that it seems like that type of workaround would likely be shunned upon in the Python community. For this case, your solution works, but in general, it would not, as it would need to be adapted for each situation.

Comment: @ClaytonGeist, the picture isn't as bad as you paint it.  I used the pattern I did for illustration purposes, I could have also used `r'([^1]|1{1,2}3)'` so your `1{1,100}` example is easily implemented.  Fewer edits to adapt than your latest solution.

Comment: @cdlane I suppose. The only thing is that it only works with `re.match`, not `re.fullmatch`. Now, yes, for this specific purpose, one could use `re.match`, but sometimes one might want to use `re.fullmatch`. Now, I've just figured out how yours can be adapted for `re.fullmatch`: `^(?![^1]|1{1,2}3).*`. The nice thing about this is that it is one byte shorter than mine! I will edit my answer. You should also edit your answer -- provide an extra point that a general purpose solution would be... Well, what you just said.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an atomic group/possessive quantifier workaround here. It involves a positive lookahead with a capturing group around its pattern, and then a backreference to this value. It will prevent backtracking into `11?` and the negative lookahead will only check for `3` once after `1` or `11`:

```
^(?=(11?))\1(?!3)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4ep1CG/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=(11?))` - a positive lookahead checking (but not advancing its index or adding the value captured to the match value) if there is `1` or `11` right at the start of the string and capturing the value into Group 1
- `\1` - a backreference to Group 1 value (now, it is atomic and does not let backtracking into the pattern (that is the issue with your pattern)
- `(?!3)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if `3` is found immediately to the right of the current location.

In Python, declare the regex with a raw string literal:

```
import re
rx = r'(?=(11?))\1(?!3)'
s = '113'
m = re.match(rx, s)
if m:
    print("Valid")
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/LWJyM6). Note the `^` is not necessary to use with `re.match` since the method only finds matches at the start of the string.

Comment: When I tried `re.fullmatch(r'^(?=(11?))\1(?!3)', '1123')` it failed to match.  And  when I tried `re.match(r'^(?=(11?))\1(?!3)', '1123')`, it matched '11', not the rest.  Is my approach to testing incorrect?

Comment: @cdlane: What is the value you need to get in the end? `re.fullmatch` requires a full string match. I thought you only need to test a value, if it passes or not. Are your input string digits only, like in my snippet? Or are you extracting them from a larger string? Or do you need to make sure there are only digits in the incoming string?

Comment: The OP is using `re.fullmatch()`, otherwise I'm sure of the exact rules here.

Comment: @cdlane And I am using `re.match` to check if a string is valid or not. That sounds appropriate judging by OP attempt. Moreover, the code is secondary here, the regex can be adjusted easily for any `re` and `regex` method.

Comment: I believe I see, it's fine if `re.match` only partially matches a correct string as long as `re.match` rejects an incorrect string.